# Failed to set State on onClick event to store id of clicked element by using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set of my useState to `id of clicked element` when user clicked it. But it shows empty string when i'm trying to console it and dispatch it. So, it feels like it didn't successfully set the state. and I don't know why.

This is the snippet code of it:

```
const Game = () => {
   const [gameMode, setGameMode] = useState('');
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   return (
       <div id='computer' className='to-play-computer' onClick={(e) => {
            setGameMode(e.currentTarget.id); // THIS DOESN'T CHANGE THE gameMode state to id 'computer'
            
            // WAIT UNTIL THIS FUNCTION DONE
            handleClickGameMode(e)
                 .then(() => {
                     console.log(gameMode); // IT WILL CONSOLE EMPTY STRING
                     dispatch(isGamePlay(gameMode));
                 })
       }}>
            <div className='icon-gameplay'>
                <FaRobot />
            </div>
            <p className='description-gameplay'>
                vs Computer
            </p>
       </div>
   )
}
```

But if assigned it to simple variable, like this:

```
let gameMode = ""; // This will store the id of clicked element
const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
       return (
           <div id='computer' className='to-play-computer' onClick={(e) => {
                gameMode = e.currentTarget.id // changed
                
                // WAIT UNTIL THIS FUNCTION DONE
                handleClickGameMode(e)
                     .then(() => {
                         console.log(gameMode); // IT WILL SUCCESSFULY CONSOLE 'COMPUTER'
                         dispatch(isGamePlay(gameMode));
                     })
           }}>
                <div className='icon-gameplay'>
                    <FaRobot />
                </div>
                <p className='description-gameplay'>
                    vs Computer
                </p>
           </div>
       )
```

So, how to make this successful using useState? And maybe you can explain me why did this happened? Because in other projects I've created, **like setState from onChange input form**, it didn't create this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(isGamePlay(gameMode));
 }, [gameMode]);
```

Comment: This is works, but i can't put it inside `.then` of `handleClickGameMode()` function above. I need to dispatch it after that function is finsihed

Comment: use ```dispatch(isGamePlay(e.currentTarget.id));```